# Compare Validator, Doesn't find the Gridview Control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I was looking in internet about this, but i can not find any answer that can help me.

My problem is that I'm trying to put a `asp:CompareValidator` inside the GridView, but when I run the aplication, I get a Error:

> "Unable to find control id 'txtQuantyDeliver' referenced by the
>   'ControlToValidate' property of 'cvEnd"

The problem is when the web page is rendering it doesn't find the control, here the code:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black"
                                                    ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                    ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-Width="80" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuanty" Text='<%# Eval("Products.Quantity") %>' />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A Despachar" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-Width="100" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <table id="tbl" class="tblMain100">
              <tr>
                  <td class="tdCenter">
                      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantyDeliver" SkinID="TextBoxesGrid" MaxLength="3" Text='<%# Eval("Products.Quantity") %>'" />
                      <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvEnd" ControlToCompare="lblQuanty" ControlToValidate="txtQuantyDeliver" Type="Integer" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server" Operator="GreaterThan" ToolTip="Solicitados <= A despachar" Text="Cantidad invilda" SkinID="cvStandard"></asp:CompareValidator>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any solution?

Comment: A couple of questions -- why are you trying to compare something to itself? That shouldn't even work. Why is that stuff in a table? Do you have more columns you just aren't showing for brevity?

Comment: I have the same question like @MikeSmithDev. Why are you to compare itself.I think its better to use CustomValidator rather than CompareValidator.

Comment: My mistake guys, i wrote fast the question and i didn't see the mistake. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: You shouldn't even be getting that error, as I don't think you can compare to a `Label` (so that is the error you should be getting). Try instead of `ControlToCompare` use `ValueToCompare='<%# Eval("Products.Quantity") %>'`.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Could you write the comment like a question to accept the answer?, becouse that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `CompareValidator`, you can't compare a TextBox to a Label. You can, however, compare it to a constant value another way:

Instead of `ControlToCompare` use `ValueToCompare='<%# Eval("Products.Quantity") %>'`

[MSDN CompareValidator Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)